# How do I scroll up/down without leaving insert mode?

Tags: vim

In Vim normal mode, you can press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd> to scroll down and up, respectively. I'm trying to make a key-bind that lets me do this from insert mode as well. This is what I've got:

```
" Scroll up and down while in insert mode.
inoremap <C-e> <C-o><C-e>
inoremap <C-y> <C-o><C-y>
```

This works like expected, but it has a big flaw. It **leaves insert mode**, scrolls, then re-enters insert mode. This is relevant when it comes to undo, repeat command etc. and I would like to be able to scroll up and down without leaving insert mode. Thoughts?

Comment: What about getting used to Vim's model of interaction instead?

Comment: @romainl: Of course, but I see no logical reason why I shouldn't be able to nudge the viewport a couple of lines up to get a specific line into view while in insert mode.

Comment: To whomever posted the second answer: Why did you delete it? :( It was very informative.

Comment: It solves the undo breakage but not the repeat-command breakage. I'll add it back and beg for help with that part :-)

Comment: Because in *insert* mode you are supposed to be typing. Not playing with your viewport. `:h scrolloff` might help you, though.

Comment: @romainl: You are right of course, but Vim is also about efficiency and minimizing keystrokes, so why `<Esc><C-e>gi` when I can just `<C-e>`?

Comment: The viewport nudging should be done *before* entering insert mode.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could take a look at `:h i_CTRL-X_CTRL-E`, which is a built-in insert-mode mapping to scroll:

```
                    *i_CTRL-X_CTRL-E*
CTRL-X CTRL-E       scroll window one line up.
        When doing completion look here: |complete_CTRL-E|

                    *i_CTRL-X_CTRL-Y*
CTRL-X CTRL-Y       scroll window one line down.
        When doing completion look here: |complete_CTRL-Y|
```

So in your case, this would probably do the trick:

```vim
inoremap <C-e> <C-x><C-e>
inoremap <C-y> <C-x><C-y>
```

Comment: +1 That is very cool, and solves my problem, but doesn't quite answer the question. If you know, could you add whether or not there is a built-in function for scrolling in Vim?

Comment: Well, you could also scroll in insert mode using your mouse scroll, dragging the scroll bar or using PageUp and PageDown, but those will all move the cursor so that's probably not what you want. In any case, it's probably more Vim-esque to do your scrolling in normal mode.

Comment: There don't appear to be any built-in functions for scrolling the window, so scripting/aliasing the mnemonics are as close as you can get. Even saved sessions and views fail to remember precise window scroll position. I've come to this conclusion after combing through the vimscript function (http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#functions) and options (http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html) references.

Comment: @Daniel: Thanks for the thorough elaboration :) Marked this answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

undojoin fixes the undo part of it:

```
ino <C-E> <Space><BS><ESC><C-E>:undojoin<CR>gi
```

The `<Space><BS>` sequence makes sure there's an undo block to join with.

Surprisingly (to me) this doesn't help with the `.` breakage, so this might leave you in just as annoying a spot as you're in now...